# Find all values that do not match a list in array of hashes in JSONB column

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

Lets say I have a table with a JSONB column named `fields`. My table `tbl_1` contains the following values,

```
ID   Fields
-------------------------------------------------------------
 1   [{"label": "Request For"}, {"label": "Requestor"}]
 2   [{"label": "Request For"}, {"label": "Meeting"}, {"label": "XYZ"}]
 3   [{"label": "Request For"}, {"label": "Meeting With"}, {"label": "ABC"}]
```

Now I have a list `["ABC", "Request For", "ZZZ", "ABC"]`. I want to find which element in the above list is not present in the table in a single query. The expected output for the above list should be `["ZZZ"]`

Comment: why "ABC" is in the output ?  it is present in the third row

Comment: @AnuraagVeerapaneni yes, it's there because it is present in the third row.

Comment: You wanted to find which element in the above list is not present in the table. But ABC is present in the table and why it should be in the output?

Comment: @AnuraagVeerapaneni Thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `not exists` in the `where` clause, example:

```
with my_table(if, fields) as (
values
    (1, '[{"label": "Request For"}, {"label": "Requestor"}]'::jsonb),
    (2, '[{"label": "Request For"}, {"label": "Meeting"}, {"label": "XYZ"}]'),
    (3, '[{"label": "Request For"}, {"label": "Meeting With"}, {"label": "ABC"}]')
)

select item
from jsonb_array_elements('["ABC", "Request For", "ZZZ", "ABC"]') as item
where not exists (
    select 1
    from my_table
    cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(fields)
    where value->'label' = item
    )

 item  
-------
 "ZZZ"
(1 row)
```

---

An alternative solution with the `@>` operator, which gives a simpler execution plan:

```
select item
from jsonb_array_elements('["ABC", "Request For", "ZZZ", "ABC"]') as item
where not exists (
    select 1
    from my_table
    where fields @> jsonb_build_array(jsonb_build_object('label', item))
    )
```

You can test on actual data which one is faster.

Answer (score 1):

This also works

```
SELECT 
    a.col
FROM
    tbl_1  t
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL
    jsonb_to_recordset(t.fields) as j("label" text)
    right join 
    (
        select unnest(ARRAY['ABC', 'Request For', 'ZZZ', 'ABC'])as col
    ) a
    on j."label" = a.col
where j."label" is null
```